# Push events and notifications from Exchange/Outlook to Google Calendar?

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-2010, google, calendar

I work in a very security-conscious environment and we use Microsoft Exchange server and Outlook for our calendaring.  However, we also all carry smart phones and I principally use Google Calendar as my *personal* scheduling system.

Is there a way to push Calendar items from Exchange or Outlook (either server-side or client-side) to Google Calendar?   I'm getting tired of missing meetings because I forgot to manually enter an Outlook Calendar item in my Google Calendar.

At my last job we used Notes and there is a smokin' awesome desktop app called [Awesync](http://www.awesync.com/) that does this for Notes, but I haven't found anything for Outlook/Exchange.

Even pushing SMS notifications from Exchange or Outlook to my phone would be great.   I investigated this as a fallback option but the only solutions seem to be commercial third-party services (essentially, business partners who are being thrown a bone by Microsoft, I think.)

What is a low- or no-cost way to solve this?  Cost will definitely be a factor.  Open source would be great but it has to be secure.    Does anyone know of anything?

Comment: http://www.pppindia.com/calendar-sync/index.html

Answer (score 0):

outlookgooglecalendarsync.codeplex.com is open source and free. It also uses oauth, so never directly knows your Google account password. Can sync attendees, reminders etc and even mask certain event subject words (using custom regex) if you're very security conscious.

Comment: What is your relationship with that site? This reads like spam, and you have posted it across other SE sites.

Comment: "Spam" seems a bit harsh, although I know there is a rule regarding blatant self promotion.  It appears to be an open source project, not a commercial one, and it does look like it would solve the problem.    Just my 2 cents.

Comment: I posted once over a year ago to comment that outlookgooglecalendarsync.codeplex.com carries on from where outlookgooglesync.codeplex.com became dormant (which the top voted answer had also recommended).

If all your spam is this targeted and provides the exact answer to a question you have at that moment, I am but very happy for you.